# Understanding git pre-commit hooks

Tags: git, github, githooks, webhooks

I am learning hooks in git and found that all hooks remain in .git folder and are local to a developer machine.I can not force all developers to place hook scripts  in there .git/hooks directory.Its up to them if they want to use or not.This goes for both client and server side hooks.
Isn't there a way that i can set certain hooks which must be  used by every developer in my team.
Suppose i want to create a pre-commit hook which will  do a sonar run,then where to configure this hook so that it reaches all developer.
I remember some where  people had used a mechanism where they are enforcing  pre-commit policies  but without any  developer  required to place hook scripts to his .git directory.
How to achieve this functionality.Is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: For client-side hooks, you can commit the hooks along with the repo, and have the first build process to copy the hooks from the build-tools directory to the git hooks directory.

Comment: totally agree with @thinkingmonster. Is there a way to provide some kind of a wrapper that sets up the git environment correctly so the team developers do not accidentally forget when they say, create a new workspace, etc?